# Trouble with drawing a simple rectangle

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have been unable to draw just a simple rectangle (programatically) in Visual Studio Express 2012 - programming in Visual Basic.

I have no problem however doing the same thing in Visual Basic Express 2010.

Firstly, I have added the reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.VS

Then in my code I import this:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks
```

then I have this code when a button is pressed:

```
Dim canvas As New ShapeContainer
Dim theShape As New RectangleShape
canvas.Parent = Me 
theShape.Parent = canvas
theShape.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(200, 300)
theShape.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(100, 100)
theShape.CornerRadius = 12
```

Unfortunately though in Visual Studio 2012, the Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks does not contain RectangleShapes (or ovals or lines for that matter) However in Visual Studio 2010 (where I have imported exactly the same Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.VS file) it does contain the Rectangle shape.

Can anyone shed any light on this problem?

Comment: I see what you mean.  Manually added the reference and imported but it didn't quite work.  I physically added a RectangleShape from my **ToolBox** to my form, though, then immediately deleted it and the problem went away.  Not sure what the difference is...

Answer (score 0):

After some research I have found that I needed to download visual studio 2012 for windows desktop. I was using visual studio 2012 for metro apps.

Thanks for the comments and help though everyone.